# compiler error error C2228: left of '.AddTail' must have class/struct/union type

Tags: visual-c++

I use CList to store my define node
but the compiler show this error C2228: left of '.AddTail' must have class/struct/union type message
I don;t know what wrong with this error message.
my code is as follow

```
TCHAR title[MAX_LEN];
 TCHAR titlestring[MAX_LEN];
 process_node node1;
 if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
 {
  int n=GetWindowText(hWnd, title, MAX_LEN-1);
  if(n>0)
  {
   _tcsncpy_s(titlestring,_countof(titlestring),(LPCTSTR)lparam,_TRUNCATE);
   _tprintf(_T("title=%s\n"),title);
  }
  if(_tcsstr(title,titlestring)!=NULL)
  {
   DWORD id=0;
   TCHAR name[MAX_LEN];
   if(hWnd)
   {
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,&id);
    GetProcessName(id,name);
    node1.ProcessID=id;
    node1.ProcessName=name;
    ProcessList.AddTail(node1);
    AfxMessageBox(_T("find"));
    _tprintf(_T("title=%s,id=%ld,name=%s\n"), title,id,name);
    return TRUE;//找完還要繼續找下一個因為有可能不只一個
   }
  }
 }
 return TRUE;
```

Comment: You can get better formatting using the code (101010) and quote (") icons on selected text.

Comment: sorry can you tell me how to format source code when post

Answer (score 0):

ProcessList just not declared.
If it does declared somethere else you should add #include  to you stdafx file.

Comment: i have define ProcessList in header file,but it still show this error message

Comment: no. I mean something like this:
#include <afxtempl.h>
...
CList<process_node> ProcessList;

Comment: @eric, you should post the definition you are referring to so we have all the information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: #ifndef _WINDOWS_TITLE_H
#define _WINDOWS_TITLE_H
#include <afxtempl.h>

Comment: I have solved this problem,via adjust CList position to .cpp file and it works

Answer (score 0):

You have this line of code:

```
  ProcessList.AddTail(node1);
```

My guess is you need something like this line of code:

```
  ProcessList myProcessList;

  myProcessList.AddTail(node1);
```

Comment: I have sovled this problem via adjust .cpp position